# Email not sending on ec2 instance running Ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, amazon-ec2, smtp

I have the following code that is used to send an email. This works fine on MAMP; but not on LAMP.

```
$config = [
    'crlf' => "\r\n",
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'newline' => "\r\n",
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtpout.secureserver.net',
    'smtp_pass' => 'password',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'username',
    'wordwrap' => true,
];
$this->load->library('email', $config);

// Send the email
$this->email->from('email@domain.com', 'Email Name');
$this->email->to('myemail@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('Subject');
$this->email->message('Message');
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
var_dump($this->email->send());
```

`false` is returned from the `var_dump` call. OpenSSL is installed. I checked my security group settings for this instance and all outbound traffic is enabled.

Comment: do you have access to the mail server log, if yes can you show us the error in the log??

Comment: My mail log doesn't show anything relevant. I'm not sure if I need to install postfix or sendmail or both.

Comment: Try debugging with [print_debugger](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#CI_Email::print_debugger)

Comment: It shows nothing

Comment: @Lance not working means on EC2 or local ??

Comment: @AbdullaNilam On ec2

Comment: is smtp host correct `'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtpout.secureserver.net',` ?? what if you use **`PHPMailer`** instead of CI mail  ??

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Yes

Comment: what if you use **`PHPMailer`** instead of CI mail ?? Read this [EC2 mail send php](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-php.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142112/discussion-between-lance-and-abdulla-nilam).

Comment: PHPMailer works on my ec2 instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggest early, I've added an example for Using PHPmailer on Amazon EC2.(Worked/Tested well)

> When you use normal mail(aws) you have to pay for it.[Read More about Amazon Simple Email Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) and  [How to setup SMTP on EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-php.html)

**Controller**

```
require_once('./phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php'); # Files attached below
require_once('./phpmailer/class.smtp.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
$mail->Port       = 587;  
$mail->Username   = "someMailAddress@gmail.com";
$mail->Password   = "password";

$to = ('to@mail.com');
$subject = 'This is and test mail from PHPMailer';

$message = 'Hi';
$message .= 'this is an mail body';

$mail->SetFrom( 'info@stackoverflow.com' , 'Stack OverFlow' );
$mail->AddAddress( $to , 'Abdulla Nilam' );
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML( $message );
$sendEmail = $mail->Send();

if( $sendEmail == true )
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'It was sent ....');
    redirect('contact');
}
else
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Nah :/ something wrong');
    redirect('contact');
}
```

[Files of PHPMailer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2iW4NyFB6ZLWkFvN2FDOVpacUU/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-JXs5z_mnEABTfbA40vvfXQ)

Comment: Can you give access to PHPMailer folder